# Android password code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an Activity that asks the user for a password to continue on the aplication. In order to do it, I have a set of passwords stored on a String[] and the program randomly asks for one each time the user starts the aplication, showing which password you have to give in a textView.
It is supposed to retrieve what the user writes in the password field 'password' and when it clicks the 'OK'button, if it is correct (I use the .equal) it will go on launching the 'menumesas' activity and doing some other stuff such as storing today's date (this is because the aplication is supposed to store the date you accessed the aplication, save it in a Data.txt file so that you get access to the application for an entire day.). To do all this date saving/reading thing I use three methods 'guardar', 'readfromfile1', 'getdate'. To get a random number to ask for one of the passwords i use the method 'dorandom'.

My problem is that the program suddently shuts down doing nothing, if i take the text view out of the code, the program works but never launches the activity 'menumesas' and i guess does nothing else,

I would really appreciate some help... please!!

```
package com.example.casino2014;




  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button okbutton;
  String tempnum="",        day1,day2,month1,month2,year1,year2,pass,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,strDate,todo,strValu     e;
 String[] datapass;
 TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.passnum);
 int random;
 int check;
 public static String TAG="MainActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.password);
    readFromFile1();
    getdate();
    dorandom();
}
    public void mybutton(View v) {

     if ((val1.equals(day1))&(val2.equals(day2))&(val3.equals(month1))&                       (val4.equals(month2))&(val5.equals(year1))&(val6.equals(year2))){
        lanzarmenumesas();
    }else{  
         // Set an EditText view to get user input   
            final EditText simpleEditText = (EditText)       findViewById(R.id.password);
             strValue = simpleEditText.getText().toString();
                if (strValue.equals("gabriel10")){
                    check=0;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Thank you, password is correct. Enjoy!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    day1=val1;
                    day2=val2;
                    month1=val3;
                    month2=val4;
                    year1=val5;
                    year2=val6;
                    char[] temporal = todo.toCharArray();
                    temporal[0]=day1.charAt(0);
                    temporal[1]=day2.charAt(0);
                    temporal[2]=month1.charAt(0);
                    temporal[3]=month2.charAt(0);
                    temporal[4]=year1.charAt(0);
                    temporal[5]=year2.charAt(0);
                    todo = new String(temporal);
                    guardar();
                    lanzarmenumesas();

    }
    }
    }
    public void dorandom(){
        random = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((99 - 0) + 1));
        datapass=new String[]{"LknbObJKkT", "JiBoloKLpR", "ZcwXZupBhy",   "epswZZVYUX", "2HWHKtabgn", "VLmHxlz5ON", "N8OyJDF2QB", "pWtx9uqO5t", "8dM6BAdhXY", "ysZIwQeb6D", "pYRPiaPULT", "IjLeTfuVsq", "6R2lcFiUs4", "PZZm9F0vih", "JUlcfpZs6I", "SlWAeaAw1w", "2xFWpravx8", "g45Toz0Xps", "oqg9VnuqML", "DpgQevBloM", "96Kmk2jtTn", "hunCWMSzvT", "PigQ46ka2Y", "e8lqt1LX83", "uxK53SyPwf", "Xd0ju1mizA", "t8Dil8StHo", "Cqh2ZLkT1T", "nfc3Tx8gUZ", "P6FZux7aSJ", "Sbw7kt7F4U", "iEAIRgVLsw", "LyEdXc43qn", "9N9ZvCyJax", "5LA4skLnhM", "K7IYRVl7R4", "nUP2hkF9Lm", "nawv8T5rUi", "4CLiLFItRQ", "Rvq1IiIR1I", "Udr47iy9Kb", "LpFbphO0Dq", "HEPstUe23O", "S25tXKKJIj", "TRrbnayyCf", "Uo90XVMG0l", "QBkmoSxn6B", "mNSvwitUHF", "Y55vlexzyw", "W5Grn0kB5C", "8TOLrOE4B2", "d1NBH8Xqao", "hlecHWq4UP", "synSXwXSk7", "q0VbZSHtcv", "7V8XcjNrG5", "6v1811VB7K", "1SGgnCVQIn", "y9HDYb43E6", "soMPOfNvsv", "JErWsN6uLa", "kIcweQuWbt", "NGcrTlHYMr", "bm8Ei3PuCZ", "K2UmC3BaHa", "1eM2Netyyr", "pkYO9pDn5L", "DGwUg1lqsk", "4MFf8kjWC5", "25QboU4GjE", "UmXHNkIRKb", "ZTMS5Nxjfi", "hnix8MTC3x", "fdL6Nku0bC", "nF27kejm3N", "BTqE2nmIb4", "fUvEL8wP6e", "VHhnCXPu8s", "YPBQWJiqfN", "9UGvP2utKC", "jVZc7qv7os", "1WMhEnPnDN", "YQ7g2P3xWs", "LqCsrMZr0q", "ABGmqvMkd6", "WrDAnUAaZF", "eEOKjsEUjb", "dvrVbx9hmj", "P1HQZkOWus", "Xs4lIAmJ2w", "bpubtCrtF5", "i6fQW1Sr8Q", "aFvcYqYhrn",        "21tfFUCf9g", "lgIS6mcDxF", "NBdWFRt0sb", "VW8zKM1XVB", "3n4Gjxjfau", "XMbQQYMMhW" };
        myAwesomeTextView.setText(random*13+"."+random+"."+(random+57));
    }
    public void lanzarmenumesas() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, menumesas.class );    
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void getdate(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yy");
        strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        val1=strDate.charAt(0)+"";
        val2=strDate.charAt(1)+"";
        val3=strDate.charAt(3)+"";
        val4=strDate.charAt(4)+"";
        val5=strDate.charAt(6)+"";
        val6=strDate.charAt(7)+"";
    }

 private void readFromFile1() {
 String nomarchivo = "Data.txt";
  File tarjeta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  File file = new File(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath(), nomarchivo);
  try {
      FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
      InputStreamReader archivo = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(archivo);
      String linea = br.readLine();
      todo = "";
      while (linea != null) {
          todo = todo + linea + "";
          linea = br.readLine();
      }
      br.close();
      archivo.close();
      day1=todo.charAt(0)+"";
      day2=todo.charAt(1)+"";
      month1=todo.charAt(2)+"";
      month2=todo.charAt(3)+"";
      year1=todo.charAt(4)+"";
      year2=todo.charAt(5)+"";
  } catch (IOException e) {
      day1="0";
      day2="0";
      month1="0";
      month2="0";
      year1="0";
      year2="0";
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
              "'Data.txt' not found!",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }
   public void guardar(){   
try {               
    File tarjeta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath(), "Data.txt");
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    for(int i=0; i<todo.length(); i++){  
    myOutWriter.append(todo);
    }
    myOutWriter.flush();
    myOutWriter.close();
    fOut.close();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Done writing to SD 'Data.txt'",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }        
finish();
  }
 }
```

My xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fifty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/passnum"
    android:layout_width="305dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="116dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have all the imports that i need, i just didnt paste them dont really know why, sorry

Comment: What do you mean with 'shuts down'? It crashes? If so, post the logcat with the stacktrace and highlight the line that causes the crash in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Without wishing to start off too negative, your question is not great. I suggest having a quick look at the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and some of the links off there. But in general:

- Ask about a specific issue you're having, rather than posting a load of code and a general request for help.
- Create one question per issue.
- (As popvitsj says) If your application is crashing then including a stack trace is a must.

That said, I remember starting out with Android and it can be a bit tricky, so here's a couple of points to help you out:

Firstly you're trying to find the TextView too early. You have the line:

```
TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passnum);
```

in your variable declarations at the top. However at this point nothing has been created, so it's not possible to find it. This is what is causing the app to crash when you try to launch it, and this is quite clear in the stack trace.

What you need to do is change it so that the variable is defined at the top:

```
TextView myAwesomeTextView;
```

But don't try to find the TextView until you're in onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.password);

    //Now things have been created, I can try to find them...
    myAwesomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passnum);
    ...
```

That will get you past the first hurdle.

Then, you'll need to add an OnClickListener to your button, so that something actually happens when you click it. E.g. (in onCreate again):

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO - Some action here
    }
});
```

Those two points will get your app to launch and actually do something when you click the button. And after that it's up to you.

If you have any more problems, raise new questions and try to be as specific as possible. Also, if you haven't done so, I really suggest you take a look at the Android tutorials and getting started. A lot of this would have been covered there.